# connecting to windows from linux

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to windows from  Linux server by python code using Winrm, but I am getting an import error

```
import winrm
s=winrm.Session('serverip', auth=('user@domain', 'password'), 
transport='ntlm')
r=s.run_cmd('ipconfig',['/all'])
r.std_out
```

The error is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "33.py", line 1, in 
>   import winrm File "/home/rajat/winrm.py", line 2, in 
>   s=winrm.Session('serverip', auth=('user@domain', 'password'),
>   transport='ntlm') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'Session'

Comment: what would you like to know, and what did you try?

Comment: which version of winrm did you installed

Comment: Is serverip the name of the server?

Comment: I am trying to connect to windows server from Linux server using Winrm I tried to use above code but it only works in python3 interactive shell, outside in 33.py I am having import errors@Nearoo

Comment: I don't know exactly how to check for Winrm version in Linux but I tried this pip install pywinrm
Requirement already satisfied: pywinrm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pywinrm) (2.22.0) {lot more already satisfied}
@LinPy

Comment: I think you need to install py3winrm

Comment: i did pip install pywinrm got output like Requirement already satisfied: pywinrm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pywinrm) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pywinrm) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pywinrm) (0.11.0)
requests-ntlm>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pywinrm) (1.1.0)
{lot more already satisfied}@LinPy

Comment: yes, you can substitute any windows server IP over there@cup

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your python file is name `winrm.py` and `import winrm` doesn't import the correct module, but instead imports your current file.

Rename your python file to something other than `winrm.py`

Reference https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/309